# Connecting to a SQL Server on the Web

Tags: sql-server, external, ports

My company had a machine running SQL Server hosted by a company specializing in such.  We have an .NET application that connects to it.

Recently the decision was made to bring the machine in house.

If we use the internal IP of the machine to connect, it works.  When we go to an outside network and use the machine's external IP, it fails.  The machine answers pings, and all of the ports in the following article have been opened.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any error message you get when trying to connect using the external IP?

Comment: Unfortunately all it says is "Unable to Connect"

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that the server is configured to accept tcp connections? open teh "SQL Server Configuration Manager". "Protocols for MSSQLSERVER" (in the tree) be sure that TCP/IP i set to enabled.

Comment: That's what it is set to.  On a lark tried setting it to both tcp/ip and named pipes.  No change

Answer (score 0):

You might need to go to 'SQL Surface Area Configuration', click on 'Remote Connections' in the treeview, then check the 'Local and Remote Connections' radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

### Firewalls

I assume you have enabled TCP/IP, and also the [SQL Browser Service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277).

Also I assume if behind a router/NAT, you have done the required Port triggering/Port forwarding.

The final thing would be make sure **all** firewalls allow SQL Server through.